# Add CMS Block to Sidebar in whole magento 2 site

Tags: magento2, cms-block, cms-pages, sidebar

When I create a static page with 2columns-left layout in magento, it has the space of sidebar on the left.
How can I put a static block in this sidebar so it can appear in every page with 2 columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your **XML** file code should be:

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
   <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="yourblockid">
       <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">yourblockid</argument>
       </arguments>
   </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: where should I put this file?

Comment: In Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

Comment: Already tried that. Not working :/

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Didn't work too

Comment: Man, sorry. The last answer worked. The problem was that I put the file in the parent theme, instead my actual theme. Thanks

Comment: Pls, return to the last answer so it can help others :)